# Concurrent sign-ups using "transaction"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, transactions

I have developed an App that allows people to sign up for events nearby, utilizing Tencent's cloud service, which is similar to Google's Firebase. The "transaction" function is employed to track the number of people who have signed up for each event.

Currently, I have set the "runTransaction" API to retry 10 times when the document is locked (edited by others) to handle concurrent sign-ups. However, during peak sign-up periods, this approach causes some users who clicked on the "purchase" button earlier to miss out on getting tickets because the API fails after 10 attempts.

I am considering increasing the maximum number of retries (e.g., to 50 or 100) for this API to ensure users who clicked the button earlier get the tickets. But I'm hesitant, as cloud functions are supposed to be fast. Presently, the memory of the cloud function is set to 256M.

So, my main questions are:

1. Would increasing the number of retries for the "runTransaction" API to 50 or 100 help mitigate this issue of missed sign-ups during high traffic periods?
2. Do you think increasing the memory of the cloud function would have any impact on resolving this problem? (My understanding is that the problem lies with the "lock" issue, not the memory or the speed of the function execution.)